# .NET Support DELETE request method in VS2010 Built In Server

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2010, rest

I am developing WCF REST services in a .NET 3.5 environment. When I debug with Visual Studio 2010 and the built in web server, I get 404 Not Found on DELETE/PUT methods when I make requests to the .svc files (using curl in cygwin specifically).

When I switch to IIS7 express as the web server, I have no problems whatsoever. Problem is this causes a ton of other issues in my environment.

My question is how do I support DELETE and PUT request methods from within the built in web server of Visual Studio 2010? Is there a setting somewhere? Do I need to edit web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason IIS Express exists is that the developer web server does not support all of the options the IIS does. You have hit on one of them (SSL support is another).

Keep using IIS Express instead of the developer web server.

Comment: This is really just for testing these WCF services. Whenever we right click the web project and say use IIS Express, that setting gets checked in through TFS...making it less than ideal. It will break things for other developers. Is there a way to use IIS Express while debugging and have it not get checked in?

Comment: @BrianScaturro - I don't know. This is more of a TFS question... Perhaps ask a specific question about the problem (configs getting checked in automatically) instead of driving for a specific solution (that in this case is not feasible).